# Taking full page screenshot in chrome store SELENIUM PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

I'm trying to save a full-page screenshot of a chrome store page, using selenium, and python 3.

I've searched online for different answers and I keep getting only the "header" part, no matter what I try. As if the page doesn't scroll for the next "section".

I tried clicking inside the page to verify it's in focus but that didn't help.
Tried answers with stitching and imported Screenshots and Image.

my current code is:

```
ob = Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)
url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/online-game-zone-new-tab/abalcghoakdcaalbfadaacmapphamklh"
driver2.get(url)
img_url = ob.full_Screenshot(driver, save_path=r'.', image_name='Myimage.png')
print(img_url)
print('done')
driver2.close()
driver2.quit()
```

but that gives me this picture:
What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: what is `Screenshot_Clipping` ? Did you tried to wait few second to load full page?

Comment: I tested `Screenshot_Clipping` with your url and I get the same result but it works correctly with some other pages. Probably page has to much JavaScript code and module has problem to correctly create screenshot. Better send it to authors of `Screenshot_Clipping` as issue. BTW: it seems they have problem with few other pages: https://github.com/PyWizards/Selenium_Screenshot/issues

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any other recommendation that can work with this site? I don't know what else to try... Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea. Selenium has `driver.save_screenshot('image.png')` but it saves only visible elements so you would have to resize window to display all page - you would have to use JavaScript to get size of page and then resize window.

Comment: Firefox has also command `:screenshot --fullpage` which you can run in console in DevTools but it may not be accesible in JavaScript so probably Selenium may not use it.

Comment: you can also try to use external portals which give API for taking screenshots - ie. [apiflash.com](https://apiflash.com/) and [examples in Python](https://apiflash.com/documentation#examples)